# No se aplica la propiedad "scroll-behaviour:smooth" cuando utilizo la propiedad "scrollTop" en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quiero que haya un smooth scroll cuando hago clic en un enlace que redirige a la parte de contacto (id=contact) y de cliente (id=client). Pero también aplico un código para hacer un scroll automático que interfiere con el smooth scroll.

Y este es el código de HTML y JavaScript con jQuery que utilizo para hacer el scroll automático:

```js
var time;
const contain = $("#contain");
const scroll_text = $("#scroll-text");
$(document).ready(function() {
  append_clone();
  pageScroll();

  contain.mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(time);
  }).mouseout(function() {
    pageScroll();
  });

});

function append_clone() {
  scroll_text.each(function() {

    scroll_text.clone().appendTo(contain);
  });
}

function pageScroll() {
  var objDiv = document.getElementById("contain");

  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 2;

  time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 100);
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#trying{
width: 100%;
min-width: 320px;
padding:50px 0;
background:var(--lightest-secondary-color)
   }

 #trying h3{
font-size: 2.6rem;
font-weight: 600;
color: var(--dark-1-primary-color);
}
#contain {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 95%;
height: 250px;
overflow-y: scroll;
border: 5px solid var(--darkest-secondary-color);
}

 #contain::-webkit-scrollbar{
display:none;
}


#scroll-text {
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding: 10px;
font-size:1.5rem;
background: var(--light-1-secondary-color);
color: var(--dark-3-primary-color);
   }

#scroll-text h4{
margin: 10px 0;
}

 #link{
  margin-top: 5px;
  display:block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color:var(--lightest-secondary-color);
 }
 #link:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
  
 #scroll-text:nth-child(odd){
  background: var(--dark-1-primary-color);
  color: var(--light-1-secondary-color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <section class="header_menu-container">
      <div class="title-container">
        <img src="images/logo_chico.jpg" alt="Bl Consultores">
        <h1>BL CONSULTORES</h1>
      </div>
      <span class="toggle-nav"></span>

      <div id="menu" class="menu-container">
        <div class="title-menu_container">
          <h3>MENU</h3>
          <span id="close-button"></span>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#client" class="scroll">Nuestros Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contacto</a></li>
            <li><a href="servicios.html">Dpto. Productos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Prefectura Naval</a></li>
            <li><a href="bases/ingreso.htm" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Consulta de Expedientes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="header-title_container">
      <h2>El mejor servicio de consultoría</h2>
      <a href="#contact">Contáctanos</a>
    </div>

  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="who-section">
      <div>
        <h3>¿Cuál es nuestro trabajo?</h3>
        <p>Nuestro trabajo profesional incluye áreas de la Propiedad Intelectual y aquellos temas relacionados con Comercialización de Productos e inscripciones, importaciones y exportaciones, especializándonos en el area de alimentos.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="images/businessman-examining-papers-at-table.jpg" alt="Consultora">
      </div>
      <section id="client" class="client-section">
       <h3>Tenemos la confianza de nuestros clientes</h3>
      </section>
    </section>
    <section id="trying">
      <h3>Te mantenemos informado</h3>
      <div id="contain">
        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>07/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2997/12 </h2>

        </div>
        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>06/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 3038/12</h4>

        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>05/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 3097/12</h4>

        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>04/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2999/12 </h4>

        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>04/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2998/12</h4>

        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>01/06/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2993/12</h4>

        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>29/05/2012 Disposicion ANMAT 2897/12</h4>

        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>Disposición 1207/2012-ANMAT - Prohibe la fabricación de mamaderas que contengan BISFENOL A</h4>
        </div>

        <div id="scroll-text">
          <h4>18/10/11 - Resolución 735/11-SENASA - PRODUCTOS ALIMENTICIOS - Aprueba Reglamento Técnico sobre Identidad y Calidad de Pimentón</h4>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="contact" class="contact-section">
   </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

La parte de  `objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 2;` es lo que da el fallo.

Agrego este texto aquí porque si no no me deja editar los cambios ya que me dice que tengo mucho codigo y pocos detalles, así que no le den importancia.

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes la propiedad `scroll-behavior: smooth`? Cuando la pongo en el CSS, funciona sin problemas con el código de la pregunta. Parece que hacen falta más detalles para ver el problema.

Comment: edite el post para agregar el resto de codigo. Espero que te sirva

Comment: He probado con tu código de nuevo y funciona perfectamente. El único problema que hay es que no tiene ninguna sección con id contact o client. Una vez las añades, funciona bien.

Comment: Veo que acabas de editar la pregunta para añadir la sección de contacto y se ve que el scroll es suave y animado.

Comment: La verdad es que no tengo idea de por qué falla, porque en mi código no funciona. Tendré que ver si en deploy funciona o si se trabaja. Gracias por tu comentario Alvaro

Answer (score -1):

No se si ya lo resolvieron, pero en mi caso tenia la opción de modo rendimiento en mi equipo. Lo cambie a mejor apariencia y ya funcionó. Parece que si quitas todos los efectos de tu sistema operativo entonces no funciona la propiedad.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/313259)